# A question about hereditary C*-subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_{0}(X)$ be the set of all continuous functions vanishing at infinity

My question is : **If $P\in M_{n}(C_{0}(X))$ is a projection, then $PM_{n}(C_{0}(X))P$ is a hereditary subalgebra of $M_{n}(C_{0}(X))$?**

Recall a C*-subalgebra $B$ of $A$ is said to be hereditary if for any $a\in A_{+}$ and $b\in B_{+}$ the inequality $a\leq b$ implies that $a\in B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a C$^*$-algebra and $p\in A$ is a projection, then $pAp$ is hereditary. For this, assume that $A\subset B(H)$, and suppose that $a\leq b$, with $a\in A$, $b\in pAp$. Then, as $p$ is a projection, $b=pbp$. From $pbp-a\geq0$, we have
$$
0\leq(I-p)(pbp-a)(I-p)=-(I-p)a(I-p).
$$
This implies that $(I-p)a(I-p)=0$. Writing $a=c^*c$, we have $[c(I-p)]^*c(I-p)=0$, so $c(I-P)=0$; then $a(I-p)=c^*c(I-p)=0$. Taking adjoint, $(I-p)a=0$. Then $a=pap\in pAp$.

*(note that the proof does not assume that $I-p\in A$, so it works even if $A$ is not unital)*

Comment: I still have two question: 1. Does $(pAp)_{+}=pA_{+}p$ hold? 2. I still do not know if $A$ is not unital, how to deal with $1-p$? I mean if $1-p \notin A$, then $(1-p)a\in "?"$ 3. Is $pAp$ closed?

Comment: The only elementI claim to belong to $A$ is $pap$, as both $a$ and $p$ are in $A$. All computations are in $B(H) $. The inclusion $pA_+p\subset (pAp)_+$ is obvious; and the other inclusion: if $x\in (pAp)_+$, then $x=pxp\in pA_+p$. If $x=\lim px_jp$, then $x=\lim px_jp=p(\lim px_jp)p=pxp$.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for your patience. :P